# jpql - How can I join tables with conditions?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```java
@Query("select distinct b from Book b" +
            " left join fetch b.reviews r" +
            " left join fetch r.user")
    List<Book> findAllWithFiveReviews();
```

There are 3 tables - books, reviews, users.

A book has reviews and each review has an user(the review's writer)

What I want to do is to fetch all books' data with recent reviews(maximum 5 reviews for each book) by adding some codes to the query.

Is it possible to fetch the data with single query? Or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that using Repository methods or CriteriaBuilder API instead of JPQL or Native Query.